# Fetching MySQL into a listview

Tags: android, mysql, listview

So I have successfully managed to create a connection via a MySQL database using this [tutorial](http://www.anddev.org/networking-database-problems-f29/connecting-to-mysql-database-t50063.html). 
The app connects to a MySQL database via a php file on a web server.

I want the results from the MySQL database to show up as a list view.
Currently it shows up like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Bk0i.jpg

Thanks in advance and hope you guys understand :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the same tutorial, now working on [this one](http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parse-read-json-data-into-a-android-listview/) to get a list view from MySQL results.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for this! I'll definitely try this out!

Comment: the link isn`t working anymore. please update the link.

Answer (score 1):

You should build a database helper that will have a method like getResults that returns a Cursor. Then wrap this cursor into a cursorAdapter and pass it to the listView.setAdapter method.

And don't forget to call startManagingCursor in your activity to avoid memory leaks.